# a question on gns construction

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $\pi$ is a zero representation of $C^*$ algebra $A$,there is no state$\tau$ on $A$ such that $\tau(a)=(\pi(a)\xi,\xi)$.

When we talk about GNS constuction,Should the zero representation be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "GNS construction" starts with a given state $\tau$. With the C$^*$-algebra $A$ and the state $\tau$ you construct a Hilbert space $H$ and a representation $\pi:A\to B(H)$.

Any state is nonzero, so the zero representation cannot arise from the GNS construction.